# Using PHP to get a list of issues from within Jira

Tags: php, soap, jira

I am entirely new to the Jira API. What I need to do is grab a list of all the issues and sort of sum the time spent on them into one number. It's basically a test report.

This looks relatively easy, but I can't seem to get the data to return from Jira... I am using PHP and my code looks something like this (With some data obviously hidden to protect anonymity) :

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://WEBADDRESS/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl");
$token = $soapClient->login('username', 'password');
$jira = file_get_contents('https://WEBADDRESS/rest/api/2/project');
print_r($jira);
```

I know that the second to last line has a URL that returns projects if I open it in the web browser, so I assume it has to have the authentication I created (And that works, I know that one) earlier... but I am just not sure how to tie them together...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up in the blog post [Searching Atlassian JIRA from an external website](http://blog.appfusions.com/searching-atlassian-jira-from-an-external-website/) but used the REST API instead.There's a little video explanation and the source code too.

Use the [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) instead - its more up to date.

Answer (score 0):

The JIRA SOAP API was deprecated in Jira 6 and will be removed in Jira 7 so use the REST API. ([Source](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/SOAP+and+XML-RPC+API+Deprecated+in+JIRA+6.0))

The example [@dvdsmpsn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1958200/dvdsmpsn) gave is also a good one.